# Error : no such partition, entering in grub rescue mode

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, grub2, dualboot

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu in my laptop. My windows was getting updated and during that process it was restarting several times. While restarting 2nd/3 rd time grub ran into problem. I am getting error:
`no such partition` and then message: `"entering grub rescue mode"` and then grub rescue prompt opens.

I have tried listing all the drives like

```
ls (hd0,msdos1)
ls (hd0,msdos2)
ls (hd0,msdos3) 
ls (hd0,msdos4)
```

All 4 commands gives error: `unknown filesystem`. Then i tried using some tricks on internet
Like

```
1) Set
2) Set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
3) set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)\boot\grub
4) insmod normal
```

This again gives error: `no such partition`

Then i created bootable pendrive for windows 10. When i select from boot menu usb storage devices then
I get message: `press enter to boot os using USB` .. when i press enter Error occurs saying

```
    Windows failed to start. 
    "Some guidelines here..."
        
    Status: 0xc0000f

Boot configurations are missing or may contain error.
```

I am constantly trying from yesterday. So if anyone have any idea can you please help me with this??

Comment: In your what? Please edit your question to make it more clear. Make certain that your sentences are complete and have a beginning and end before moving on the to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to recover windows 10 in such situations when grub fails to take a control or grub configuration files are corrupted or deleted or may be dislocated. After so many efforts, i got to knew about Boot repair disk OS. Before that i tried many solutions on forums most of them saying get bootable usb for windows with same version that you have and then boot using usb and repair using repair your computer option that comes when we try to boot OS using USB. But in my case, as i told in my question booting from usb was also giving error: Boot configuration files are missing or having errors. In such case, what you need to do to solve the problem is create a bootable USB for Boot Repair disk OS use fat32 filesystem and all other default settings for creating this bootable USB. Using this bootable USB, you have to now load this boot repair disk os.
For doing that in bios settings, set legacy mode on, bios security disabled and keep usb device on top priority inside bios->boot sequence. (On dell laptop you can enter into bios by using F2 key). After that reboot computer and now go to boot menu (on dell laptop to enter into boot menu you can use f12 key) then in legacy option select USB storage device (You can switch between options by up /down arrow keys). Once you press enter by selecting USB option in legacy mode booting of BOOT REPAIR DISK OS will start and then OS will be loaded. This takes some time based on computer hardware.
Once OS is loaded successfully, you will get boot repair icon their on task bar. Click on that and then click on recommended repair. This will solve your issue. After successful repairing the boot info window popups up. You can choose yes or no. Now you can just right click->logout->reboot. Once system shuts down remove bootable usb and turn on your system. You'll see Your windows OS will be loading and all the files are recovered successfully.